# See all tables, all records from console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I display the current record counts from all my database tables in one command using the console? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will do it if you've 'touched' all your classes, but only for actual models:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.map { |c| "#{c.name} => #{c.count}" }
```

If you really want all tables, including join tables that don't map to models:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.map { |t| "#{t} => " + ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select count(*) from #{t}").fetch_row.first}
```

Comment: The second command is giving me a Mysql error `You have an error in your SQL syntax... check for the right syntax to use near 'references' at line 1: select count(*) from references`.

Comment: 'references' is a reserved word in MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html). It will probably work if you put quotes or backtics around #{t}.

Comment: For Postgresql with Rails 3.2.x, the 2nd statement needed to be tweaked to:

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.map { |t| "#{t} => " + ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select count(*) from #{t}").first['count'] }`

Answer (score 16):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
```

this will return an array of the tables you have, if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little longer than what you were hoping for, but hope this helps ;-)

```
Dir.glob('app/models/*.rb').each {|file| puts eval(File.basename(file, ".rb").classify + '.count').to_s + " #{File.basename(file, ".rb").classify.pluralize}"}
```

It might be better to create a rake task for this.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for this! I have a peculiar error - I have a model called 'Address' and due to pluralize it is giving me the error `NameError: unitialized constant Addres`. Sorry for the issue - how can I get past this?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this and I came up with my own way of doing this.

I like to encapsulate if into a model called **Maintenance** that is not a active record model

my model looks like

```
class Maintenance
  def self.show_all_tables_count
    list_table_with_count = []
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
      unless ['ar_internal_metadata', 'schema_migrations'].include?(table)
        list_table_with_count << [name: table, count: table.singularize.camelize.constantize.count]
      end
    end
    list_table_with_count
  end
end
```

I hope that this helps